# Animate text in div using css when change

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am changing the innerText of #val, I keep the code as simple as possible

Is there any way to slide in value when text changes?

Edit: I have a container, in this example `val` and the text inside change base on some conditions, I want to slide in the text when new values applied

```js
var i = 0;
function getValue(){
let mes = '';
  if( i %3 == 0)
    mes= 'This is A'
   else if(i %3 == 1)
    mes= 'This is B'
  else
    mes= 'this is C'
i= i+1;
document.getElementById("val").innerText = mes;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="getValue()" value="button">
<div id="val">

</div>
```

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. What is the purpose you are trying to gain or what error are you facing here ?

Comment: @MushfiqurRahmanAbir I add more description to question

Comment: can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I should upload my whole project for that, I did explain the my purpose in the question

Comment: you wrote - "want to slide in the text when new values applied", but what do you mean? it is not clear.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes, I did, and I mean I have some conditions, base on this conditions the value of some container changes. I want to slide in the value when new values are applied, for example the content of my container is 'A' at this time, a condition changes and I want to show 'B', so I want 'B' slides in when content changed to 'B'

Comment: I perfectly understand the logic of your code, but it was not clear to me what type of animation was needed.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov slide in, fade in, scale any kind of animation would be fine

Answer (score 1):

I used the `animate()` method together with the rule of `opacity`. Gradation animation is quite strict.

Was it necessary?

```js
var i = 0;
function getValue(){
let mes = '';
  if( i %3 == 0)
    mes= 'This is A'
   else if(i %3 == 1)
    mes= 'This is B'
  else
    mes= 'this is C'
i= i+1;
document.getElementById("val").innerText = mes;
document.getElementById("val").animate([
    { transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: '0' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-90%)',  opacity: '0.1' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-80%)',  opacity: '0.2' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-70%)',  opacity: '0.3' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-60%)',  opacity: '0.4' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-50%)',  opacity: '0.5' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-40%)',  opacity: '0.6' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-30%)',  opacity: '0.7' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-20%)',  opacity: '0.8' },
    { transform: 'translateX(-10%)',  opacity: '0.9' },
    { transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: '1' }           
      ], { 
            duration: 500,            
         });
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="getValue()" value="button">
<div id="val">

</div>
```

Second solution, from the category of `fadein`:

```js
var i = 0;

function getValue(){
let mes = '';
  if( i %3 == 0)
    mes= 'This is A'
   else if(i %3 == 1)
    mes= 'This is B'
  else
    mes= 'this is C'
i= i+1;

let opacity = 0.01;
let anim_time = setInterval(function() {   
        if(opacity >= 1) {          
            clearInterval(anim_time);       
        }       
        document.getElementById("val").style.opacity = opacity; 
    document.getElementById("val").innerText = mes;
        opacity += opacity * 0.1;   
    }, 10); 
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="getValue()" value="button">
<div id="val">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make another function where the left align changes with setTimeout in a self iteration and make <div id = 'val' onChange = 'function()'